# Simple Debugger and Hardware BreakPoints in x64 Windows 10

Tags: debuggers, breakpoint

I have coded a very simple Debugger for x64, I am using currently Win10.

I am trying to set some Hardware Breakpoints to be trapped by my Debugger Loop as follows:

```
inline void SETBITS(DWORD64 *dw, int lowBit, int bits, int newValue) {

     int mask = (1 << bits) - 1;
     *dw = (*dw & ~(mask << lowBit)) | (newValue << lowBit);

}

BOOL SetHardwareBP(HANDLE hThread, __int64 Address, DWORD Length, int Condition)
{

    CONTEXT context = { CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS };
    int i;
    if (!GetThreadContext(hThread, &context)) return -1;

    // find available hardware register

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
    if ((context.Dr7 & (1 << (i * 2))) == 0)
    {
        *(&context.Dr0 + i) = Address;

        SETBITS(&context.Dr7, 16 + i * 4, 2, Condition);
        SETBITS(&context.Dr7, 18 + i * 4, 2, Length);
        SETBITS(&context.Dr7, i * 2, 1, 1);

        if (!SetThreadContext(hThread, &context))
            return -1;

        return i;
    }
  }

   return -1;
}

int SetDebugPrivileges(void) {

      TOKEN_PRIVILEGES priv = { 0 };
      HANDLE hToken = NULL;

      if (OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken)) {
        priv.PrivilegeCount = 1;
        priv.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

        if (LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_DEBUG_NAME, &priv.Privileges[0].Luid)) {
        if (AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &priv, 0, NULL, NULL) == 0) {
            printf("AdjustTokenPrivilege Error! [%u]\n", GetLastError());
        }
    }

       CloseHandle(hToken);
  }
       return GetLastError();
}


void ThreadsLoop(DWORD mPID) {

   HANDLE         hProcessSnap = NULL;

   SetDebugPrivileges();
   hProcessSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0);

   if (hProcessSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return;

    else
    {
    THREADENTRY32 the;
    the.dwSize = sizeof(THREADENTRY32);

    BOOL bret = Thread32First(hProcessSnap, &the);
    while (bret)
    {


        if (the.th32OwnerProcessID == mPID)
        {

            HANDLE hthread = OpenThread(THREAD_ALL_ACCESS, false, the.th32ThreadID);
            SuspendThread(hthread);

                           //call with length and condition set to 0 for a Code Execution type
            int hr = SetHardwareBP(hthread, addr, 0, 0);
            ResumeThread(hthread);

            CloseHandle(hthread);
        }
        bret = Thread32Next(hProcessSnap, &the);
    }
    CloseHandle(hProcessSnap);
}
}
```

I am calling
`ThreadsLoop(pi.dwProcessId);` where pi is the the PROCESS_INFORMATION structure returned from my initial call:

```
CreateProcess(pname, NULL, NULL, NULL, false, DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS, NULL,NULL, &si, &pi);
```

None of the Hardware Breakpoints is Hit. I did several attempts changing the DR0-DR7 (and condition and length variables above) setup without luck. All calls to SetThreadContext returned successfully.

I did the same test with a Software Breakpoint via the following code and works perfect:

```
BYTE p[] = { 0xcc }; 
SIZE_T d = 0;
WriteProcessMemory(pi.hProcess, (void*)addr, p, sizeof(p), &d);
```

What could be wrong in this code/approach?

Thanks

Comment: Has "SETBITS" function implemented in a way that changes the DR7 value and then you set it by calling SetThreadContext?...

Comment: To make it more clear you send some inputs to the functions, and receiving NO output and just setting the context which has the same DR7 :) I think you now understand what's wrong...

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this. I fixed the code. Still the breakpoints not working.

Comment: Now again you have a problem... Look again. You're changing the pointer itself not the value which the pointer points to.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it. It was a typo. The code, is still not BP.

Comment: I also don't see anywhere you define hardware bp type

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69771/discussion-between-fred26-and-ewd-0).

Comment: Those who put this on hold cuz they think it's not related to reversing have to get more info about reversing... Reversing is not just about using debuggers!!! It's also about development of tools to debug/reverse and analysis of an executable. And the questions related to debuggers are all related to the topic!

Comment: As @EWD-0- says there is very little or no documentation on how to implement the debugger API so I think is pertinent to leave this question open as it is part of reverse engineering.

Comment: @fre26 Very good point... Actually we were doing sm reversing to see how it's working though I posted the link where is explains which event we receive in the case of hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues you have to fix

1. Please take a look at [This](http://winappdbg.sourceforge.net/HowBreakpointsWork.html) where is explains which event is triggered in the hardware breakpoint case. You have to add **EXCEPTION_SINGLE_STEP** in **DebuggerThreadProc()** function
2. You need to be attached to the target process in order to be able to debug it. For this you need to use  [DebugActiveProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679295(v=vs.85).aspx)
3. This one is quite a semantic error. As you create the target process in the same app you already have an open handle to both the process and the main thread so there is NO need to create snapshot and searching for the target! This is completely redundant. Please remove all these parts and pass the handles as input to those functions.
4. Always keep in mind to **close** the handles you've opened.

Comment: your **2.** is wrong. not need call `DebugActiveProcess` if we create process with `DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS` or `DEBUG_PROCESS` flags. also need handle not only  `EXCEPTION_SINGLE_STEP` but also `STATUS_WX86_SINGLE_STEP` - this will be if we debug wow64 process

Comment: Last one first, during the questions I've asked it was mentioned that the target is x64. If not, there are other APIs which has to be added to make it compatible not only STATUS_WX86_SINGLE_STEP. Other thing which I didn't mention here but in the chat is that though the values might be the same it's better to use EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT instead of STATUS...

Comment: the `STATUS_WX86_SINGLE_STEP` (and `STATUS_WX86_BREAKPOINT` on breakpoint) come when exception was in wow64 code. and debugger is 64bit process. if we debug x64 process we of course never get this exception codes. however always better handle it too, for not restrict self for x64 apps only. *there are other APIs which has to be added to make it compatible* dont know what you mean, but x64 debugger perfect can debug both 32 and 64 processes with single code base without any special api calls

Comment: As Igor also mentioned in chat, consider Wow64Get/SetThreadContext as an example. I think the best way is to add your points as another answer... Better than in the comments.

Comment: And about starting with DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS/DEBUG_PROCESS you're right, this is ALSO another way to receive dbg events. The "2" is not wrong it's one of the ways and the one you've mentioned another way.

Comment: when i say that not need separate `DebugActiveProcess` i mean only concrete case - we at begin create process with debugging. `DebugActiveProcess` need in case when we want debug already running process, which we not create. however this api not the best even in this case, because create additional thread in target process, which absolute not needed. i prefer `DbgUiDebugActiveProcess` use here.

Comment: about separate Wow64 context - this is optional and almost not need. when we got exception from thread - always need use native, 64bit context. call exactly Get/SetThreadContext. when we debug wow64 code - the wow64 context the same as 64bit context (in sense *Eip==Rip,Esp==Rsp, Eax==Rax..*). after we enter 64 gate (`CpupReturnFromSimulatedCode`) - first several instruction Wow64 context is invalid at all and then Wow64 context point to context from where we jump to native code and not changed until we return to wow64. so debugger must exactly call Get/SetThreadContext for main task.

Comment: may say that Get/SetThreadContext always return true/actual user mode context of thread (does not matter this is thread from 32 or 64 bit process). the wow64 context really sub-context of wow64 part of thread execution only - equal to native context when thread in wow64 segment and not changed until thread executed in native segment. and it can be also queried via `ZwQueryInformationThread(..ThreadWow64Context..)`